# is there R package and fucntion for making descriptive tables that are suitable for a report?

Tags: r, summary

I have a df called crash_speed detailing the number of crashes, casualties and deaths for each speed interval (from 10-110). It looks like the follwing:

[image: df]

I'm just wondering how I'd go about in plotting a table of this, and what packages and fucntions to use ect. I pretty much want to just keep the same, but just plot it

Answer (score 1):

I think **knitr**, **kable** , and **kableExtra** are the things you are looking for.
For more info check the docs:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Before posting a question please do your own research on finding a topic as said in general terms of posting.
This answer took 1 minute of googling :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `gridExtra`

```
library(gridExtra)
df <- iris[1:10,]
grid.table(df)
```

This outputs to the plot window the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either try out the [table functions of ggpubr](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggtexttable.html) or dive into numerous packages. The easiest way to get started is the **[gt package](https://gt.rstudio.com/)** which also provides a list of alternatives like

- **knitr** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/yihui/knitr), [WEBSITE](https://yihui.org/knitr/))
- **kableExtra** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra), [WEBSITE](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/))
- **formattable** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable), [WEBSITE](https://renkun-ken.github.io/formattable/))
- **DT** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/rstudio/DT), [WEBSITE](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/))
- **pander** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander), [WEBSITE](http://rapporter.github.io/pander))
- **huxtable** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable), [WEBSITE](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/))
- **reactable** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/glin/reactable), [WEBSITE](https://glin.github.io/reactable/))
- **flextable** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable), [WEBSITE](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/))
- **ftextra** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/atusy/ftExtra), [WEBSITE](https://ftextra.atusy.net/))
- **pixiedust** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/nutterb/pixiedust))
- **tangram** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/spgarbet/tangram))
- **ztable** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/cardiomoon/ztable))
- **condformat** ([GITHUB](https://github.com/zeehio/condformat))
- **stargazer** ([CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer))
- **xtable** ([CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=xtable))

I do also know at least one blog [writing about gt tables](https://themockup.blog/#category:gt) and the author of the blog additionally maintains [a gt extension package](https://jthomasmock.github.io/gtExtras/).